# OAuth 1.0 A Invalid Signature when requesting request token (SalesForce/JIRA Integration)

Tags: oauth, salesforce, jira, apex

I've been trying my darndest to avoid asking a question. I'm recieving an invalid signature error when trying to request a request token from JIRA from within Salesforce. The response I'm getting is:

> 08:15:24:201 USER_DEBUG [30]|DEBUG|
>   oauth_problem=signature_invalid
>
> &oauth_signature=RaOPaBPznmS7aDUuJN1pOclcyHWP4uRYYx4j%2F%2BdtKB1SD4l1JcCCys3P3RAa8P7377MwLsIMBtkHfL62jaXr5LV30RndjVUSlCsVl3h47CvinHgDtTMwWGukQJXhOmSsLPvccCqD7qsRmiQnnjSJCwd9YKJEi2cxNcwMqhnceqAwJdzn3RD%2FBBeNpf3G97wqWhJx%2FtyEhQGk35OTu00fhtw%2BIX025STN3iiGNbyANlmoImAGWqAJeqJOPUVva7TR2OAInysL9%2BHmYkQTOcb7a9sn5rRWUqE4Jua6EoVyPgzJnSgZ4pFEIMzU0eTWQqhSFdQwOdnoq5EQU8W%2BPJM8uA%3D%3D
>
> &oauth_signature_base_string=POST%26https%253A%252F%252F.atlassian.net%252Fplugins%252Fservlet%252Foauth%252Frequest-token%26oauth_consumer_key%253D3MVG9KI2HHAq33RwCPH5bNzAHbOgfiicjJ6HjvVfNhGU8aWXGl6ps.vsEzobCPqRXuDcmeV2Baw%25253D%25253D%2526oauth_nonce%253D-6826921263934288296%2526oauth_signature_method%253DRSA-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1492182924
>
> &oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1

The code I'm using to try to generate the signature is:

```
// GitHub OAuth Playground: https://github.com/jesperfj/sfdc-oauth-playground/blob/master/OAuth/src/classes/OAuth.cls
// OAuth Bible: http://oauthbible.com/
// Static Values
String consumerKey = '3MVG9KI2HHAq33RwCPH5bNzAHbOgfiicjJ6HjvVfNhGU8aWXGl6ps.vsEzobCPqRXuDcmeV2Baw==';
String endpoint = 'https://<AtlassianSiteName>.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token';

// Params
String callbackParam = '&oauth_callback=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('https://localhost/', 'UTF-8');
String consumerKeyParam = '&oauth_consumer_key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(consumerKey, 'UTF-8');
String signatureMethodParam = '&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1';
String timestampParam = '&oauth_timestamp=' + String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);
String nonceParam = '&oauth_nonce=' + String.valueOf(crypto.getRandomLong());
String versionParam = '&oauth_version=1.0';
String paramString = consumerKeyParam + nonceParam + signatureMethodParam + timestampParam + versionParam + callbackParam;

// Get baseString
String baseString = 'POST&' + encodingUtil.urlEncode(endpoint, 'UTF-8') + paramString;

system.debug(baseString);

blob sig = crypto.signWithCertificate('RSA-SHA1', blob.ValueOf(baseString), 'SelfSignedCert_26Oct2015_184625');
String signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');

httpRequest req = new httprequest();
http http = new http();
req.setEndPoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setBody(paramString +
           '&oauth_signature=' + signature);

httpresponse res = http.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

**Note:** Yes I understand that I probably shouldn't be sharing some of this information but these are my personal test orgs that contain nothing important and I'm not providing the SSL used. You'll notice some comments at the top of my code containing a few urls to my favorite resources that have gotten me this far. These are not the only resources I've used, just the most useful ones.